# Laravel 5.7 - multiply two columns and add to final sum

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables - a students table and a products table.

When i make a list of the students in a table, i need to see the total amount (sum) of payments that has been made, unfortunately it seems like the result is the correct sum but multiplied by the amount of rows.

**Students table**:

```
+----+----------+
| id |   name   |
+----+----------+
|  1 | Jonathan |
|  2 | Bob      |
+----+----------+
```

**Products table**:

```
+----+------------+-------+----------+
| id | student_id | money | quantity |
+----+------------+-------+----------+
|  1 |          1 |  1000 |        2 |
|  2 |          1 |  2000 |        1 |
|  3 |          2 |   500 |        5 |
|  4 |          2 |  3000 |        1 |
+----+------------+-------+----------+
```

**Payments table**:

```
+----+-------+------------+
| id | money | student_id |
+----+-------+------------+
|  1 |  5000 |          1 |
|  2 |  2000 |          1 |
|  3 |  2500 |          2 |
|  4 |  2500 |          2 |
+----+-------+------------+
```

In theory, the output of my query **should** be:

```
+-------------+----------+----------------+----------------+
| id          |   name   | payments_total | products_total |
+-------------+----------+----------------+----------------+
|           1 | Jonathan |  4000          |           7000 |
|           2 | Bob      |  5500          |          10000 |
+-------------+----------+----------------+----------------+
```

**What i have tried**:

```
        $teamStudents = DB::table('students')->where('students.team', $team)->orderBy('first_name', 'ASC') 
                                ->join('products', 'students.id', '=', 'products.student_id')
                                ->join('payments', 'students.id', '=', 'payments.student_id')
                                ->select('students.first_name AS first_name', 'students.last_name AS last_name', 'students.created_at AS created_at', DB::raw('SUM(products.money * products.amount) AS products_total'), DB::raw('SUM(payments.money) AS payments_total'), 'students.id AS id')
                                ->groupBy('students.id')
                                ->get();
```

It returns no error except for the fact that the returned "payments_total" is inaccurate and multiplied by the amount of rows for some reason.

So my question is:
How do i get around this and what have i done wrong? I've been googling for an hour with no result.

Is my query an issue or the way i've set it up, if so, what would the correct solution be?

Comment: I just re-created exactly as you have, the tables with the same data, using exactly the same query and I get the result that you expect. So I am not sure what you are doing wrong.

Comment: If you have an extra table called payments2 and just make it with same contents and columns, then try adding a secondary join. Then it'll fail for sure, but how.

Comment: well, from what you have shared and what you expect it works as it should. You need to share the real problem that you have so I know what to help you with.

Comment: Ohh damn, i had added it, seems my changes hadn't been applied for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your edit I was able to solve the problem that you have, but in your edit you use couple of things for which I don't have data, such as the `$team`, `first_name` and `last_name` of the students. But anyway, here is a solution for your problem, you have to use subqueries in order to solve this:

```
$teamStudents = DB::table('students')->orderBy('name', 'ASC')
    ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(select SUM(products.money * products.quantity) AS products_total, student_id from products group by student_id) products'), 'students.id', '=', 'products.student_id')
    ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(select sum(payments.money) as payments_total, student_id from payments group by student_id) payments'), 'students.id', '=',
        'payments.student_id')
    ->select('students.name', 'payments.payments_total', 'products.products_total', 'students.id AS id')
    ->groupBy('students.id')
    ->get();
```

I am not sure if technically I will be correct, but the problem is because you use multiple joins, so that's why the results are doubled, if you don't use subqueries.

Comment: That works perfectly, question is though, why? Do i have to make my joins as subqueries for it to work? I can see that i'd have to group them by student id in the joined tables, but i thought it would do that itself.. guess you'll learn something new everyday.

Comment: That's how the join works. If you try without group by then you will see all the results doubled for each row found in the joined table. So not always using subqueries, but when you need to do sum yes, because the sum works by grouping. I hope this helps somehow, I am not really a DB guy, but luckily I know how to get my way around it :)

Comment: Oh theres an issue apparently, if there are no payments or products registered for the user, nothing is returned..

Comment: You can use left join then, because the default is inner join.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to join in this case, you don't use it anyways.

```
$teamStudents = DB::table('students')
    ->select('id, name')
    ->selectRaw('select sum(money) from payments where student_id = students.id as payments_total')
    ->selectRaw('select sum(money) from products where student_id = students.id as products_total')
    ->orderBy('name')
    ->get();
```